# Trying to create web automatic tool with Selenium, however the website won't load

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I am trying to  build a basic web automation tool for office purposes.
I've followed some guides and am able to at least get the script to detect the driver and open the browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ava/Webautomator/chromedriver') #filepath of the driver
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

However, when attempting to load 'google.com' I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webautomator2.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver.get("www.google.com")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)
```

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: Please use https with your url, that should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this

```
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

To this

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```